# Solid spheres are penetrating solid walls of the alphabet L

Tags: animation, cinema-4d

I have been trying tweaking properties and settings but cannot find the solution.
The problem is that the solid RED balls are visible through the GREEN walls which is really very unwanted.

Please have a look at the image for better understanding.[image: Problem Image]

I want that the red balls should come out from the opening that has been made, and not from the walls of the alphabet `L`. please suggest appropriate measures and also explain why is this happening.

Comment: I would also like to add that this happens only in 3-5 frames when the spheres blast, and afterwards it renders perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to play around with the dynamics settings. You can get there by pressing CTRL-D for the project settings and selecting the "Dynamics" -> "Expert" tab. Try increaseing the "Steps per Frame" value. This sets how often the dynamics are calculated per frame and gives you a more precice calculation - of course it does take more time for the dynamics to calculate.

Comment: If the spheres are passing through the "solid" wall it usually comes from a missed collision detection. Have you tried _really_ increasing the "Steps per Frame" value - like, setting it to 500? Can you make the cloner bigger or make less or smaller spheres, so they won't have that much speed after the "explosion"?

Comment: Reducing the number of clones will solve the problem but I don't want to reduce them, this will spoil the **burst-out** effect. Yes, I have really tried increasing the number of steps per frame.